# How to share common settings betwen 2 dojo application build profiles

Tags: build, dojo

We have 2 different builds of our dojo application, using either `ourapp.profile.js` or `ourapp.custom.profile.js` which contain the dojo application build profile.

Apart from a few differences in the `layers` property the rest of these 2 files are virtually identical. What's the best way to share the common settings between these 2 files?

Here's a simplified example of one our application profiles

```js
var profile = (function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        basePath: "../",
        releaseDir: "../../../build",
        releaseName: "js",
        action: "release",

        dirs: ["../css", "../css/font", "../img", "../img/icons", "../stylus/themes/common"],

        packages: [
            {
                name: "dbootstrap",
                location: "dbootstrap"
            },
            {
                name: "dgrid",
                location: "dgrid"
            },
            {
                name: "dstore",
                location: "dstore"
            },
            {
                name: "dijit",
                location: "dijit"
            },
            {
                name: "dojo",
                location: "dojo"
            },
            {
                name: "dojox",
                location: "dojox"
            },
            {
                name: "ourapp",
                location: "ourapp"
            },
            {
                name: "lib",
                location: "lib"
            },
            {
                name: "xstyle",
                location: "xstyle"
            },
            {
                name: "specs",
                location: "specs"
            }
        ],
        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: [
                    "dojo/dojo",
                    "dojo/i18n",
                    "dojo/domReady",
                    "ourapp/boot",
                    // more includes
                    ...
                ],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true,
            },
            // other layers
            ...

        },

        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        mini: 1,
        stripConsole: "warn",
        selectorEngine: "lite",
        insertAbsMids: false,
        staticHasFeatures: {
            "config-deferredInstrumentation": 0,
            // More settings
            ..
        },

        defaultConfig: {
            hasCache: {
                "dojo-built": 1,
                "dojo-loader": 1,
                "dom": 1,
                "host-browser": 1,
                "config-selectorEngine": "lite"
            },
            async: 1
        }
    };
})();
```

Ideally we'd like both files to share one common set of settings and just specify the parts that differ in our 2 application profiles.

### Update:

[This page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/buildSystem.html#mixing-multiple-profile-sources) talks about multiple profile sources so I'm going to try splitting out the common parts to another profile file then when building running something like:

`>build.bat --profile ourapp.shared.profile.js --profile ourapp.profile.js`

or

`>build.bat --profile ourapp.shared.profile.js --profile ourapp.custom.profile.js`

Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested in the Update to the question does work, but isn't very well documented about how different profile properties are combined or replaced so required some trial and error as certain properties are treated differently.

What we have now is the profile shown in the question (ourapp.profile.js), and ourapp.custom.profile.js as follows:

```
var profile = (function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        basePath: "../",
        releaseName: "js-custom",

        packages: [
            {
                name: "ourapp",
                location: "ourapp-custom"
            }}
        ]
    };
})();
```

Now for our custom build we run this from the command line:

> build.bat --profile ourapp.profile.js --profile ourapp.custom.profile.js

The properties in ourapp.custom.profile.js replace those in ourapp.profile.js changing the release name to 'js-custom' and replace the standard ourapp package with an alternative one in ourapp-custom.